# Mortgage calculator for homework

Tags: c++, homework, finance

I needed to create a mortgage calculator for an intro to CS class. As part of the assignment, with an interest rate of 6% needs to change to 7% after 3 years hence that `if` statement. The `char` dummy line at the end is a requirement from my professor.

I'm mainly looking for ways to clean it up or if I missed anything. I'm required to use `namespace std`, and I know a lot of you don't care for it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double monthlyPayment;
    double balance;
    double interestRate;
    double interestPaid;
    double initialBalance;
    double termOfLoan;
    double month = 1;

    cout.setf(ios::fixed);  
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    cout << "Enter the current balance of your loan: $";
    cin >> balance;
    cout << "Enter the initial yearly interest rate : ";
    cin >> interestRate;
    cout << "Enter the desired monthly payment : $";
    cin >> monthlyPayment;

    initialBalance = balance;

    while (interestRate >= 1)       /*Converts the interest rate to a decimal if the user inputs 
                                                      in percentage form*/
    { 
        interestRate = interestRate / 100; 
    }

    if(month >= 36);
    { 
        if(interestRate=.06)
        {
            interestRate=.07;
        }
    }
    balance = balance * (1 + interestRate / 12) - monthlyPayment;

    cout << "After month 1 your balance is $" << balance << endl;

    while (balance > 0)
    {
        if (balance < monthlyPayment)
        {
            balance = balance - balance;
        }   
        else 
        {
            balance = balance * (1 + interestRate / 12) - monthlyPayment;
        }

        month = month++;
        month = month + 1;
        month += 1;     

        cout << "After month " << month << ", your balance is : $" << balance << endl;
        }
        cout << "You have paid off the loan at this point. Congratulations!" << endl;


        termOfLoan = month;

interestPaid = (monthlyPayment * termOfLoan) - initialBalance;      

/*I believe the formula above would work if only there was
 a way to calculate how many months it took to pay 
off the loan, but since it varies, I don't know how to 
calculate "termOfLoan". */

            cout << "You paid a total ammount of $" << interestPaid << " in intrest." << endl;
            cout << "Total number of months = " << month << "." << endl;

char dummy;
cout << "Enter any key to quit." << endl;
cin >> dummy;
}
```

Comment: When you say the interest rate changes from 6% to 7% after 3 years, does this mean that it increases by 1% every 3 years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You use `double` values for calculations. Especially for money, I would suggest to switch to `int` and handle it in cents. That way you can avoid problems with floating point precision.
2. You don't check if `cin>>` fails or succeeds. If the user doesn't enter a number you may have a problem here. A possible solution might be to let the user reenter the value as long as it isn't correct.

   ```
   do
   {
       cout << "Enter the current balance of your loan: $";
   }
   while (!(cin >> balance));
   ```
3. You have a wrong check in the line `if (interestRate = .06)`. You probably meant `if (interestRate == .06)`. Additionally, this check might also be a problem as you do some calculations on `interestRate` that may cause inprecision (again floating point precision problem).

   As you obviously await the user to input the value as `int` your check should be against `6` before you divide the value with `100`.
4. You have this piece of code:

   ```
   if (balance < monthlyPayment)
   {
       balance = balance - balance;
   }
   ```

   Which is the same as:

   ```
   if (balance < monthlyPayment)
   {
       balance = 0;
   }
   ```

   I think the second version is easier to understand.

I didn't check any more of the code yet. I especially didn't prove it for correctness in you calculations.

Comment: That's very helpful! What's the advantages of using *int* here over double? My very basic understanding of it is that double is better suited to handle decimals.

Comment: @JonathanHall I would recommend you to have a look at [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples) examples. There is also an [article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) about the problems with floating point precision.  But see for yourself: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96637ffdb47780d4

Comment: @JonathanHall: Please be aware that if you use integer values these are always round to the lower bound. `3/2` is `1` and not `1.5`.

Answer (score 2):

**Use of `while` where `if` is appropriate**

You have:

```
while (interestRate >= 1)
{ 
   interestRate = interestRate / 100; 
}
```

I believe that should be an `if`.

```
if (interestRate >= 1)
{ 
   interestRate = interestRate / 100; 
}
```

**Wrong place for `if (month >= 36)`**

You have:

```
if(month >= 36);
{ 
   if(interestRate=.06)
   {
      interestRate=.07;
   }
}
```

The first error is that you have an errant `;` in the `if` line.

```
if(month >= 36);  // This terminates the if statement
```

The block

```
   if(interestRate=.06)
   {
      interestRate=.07;
   }
```

is executed no matter what.

Also, as has already been pointed out by the other answer, you need to use

```
   if(interestRate == .06)
```

The other point is that you need to move this check inside the subsequent `while` loop. Otherwise, the conditional `month >= 36` will always evaluate to false since `month` has been initialized to `1`.

**Updating `month`**

Inside the `while` loop, you have:

```
  month = month++;     // This is bad code. It leads to UB.
  month = month + 1;   // Increment month by 1
  month += 1;          // Increment month by 1 again.
```

It's not clear to me what you are trying to do here.

I think you should change the type of  `month` from type `double` to `int` and have just one line to increment its value.

This is how I see the `while` loop.

```
int month = 1;

...


while (balance > 0)
{
   if(month >= 36)
   { 
      if ( interestRate == .06 )
      {
         interestRate = .07;
      }
   }

   if (balance < monthlyPayment)
   {
      balance = 0;
   }   
   else 
   {
      balance = balance * (1 + interestRate / 12) - monthlyPayment;
   }

   cout << "After month " << month << ", your balance is : $" << balance << endl;

   ++month;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Bug

```
if(interestRate=.06)
```

You should use `==`, [as explained in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359433/if-statement-with-equal-sign-and-not-in-expression)

Right now it counts as always true, look at this example:

```
~$ cat ifeq.c
int main() {
  int x = 1;
  if (x = 2) {
    puts("hi");
  }
}
~$ gcc ifeq.c && ./a.out
hi
```

#### Listen to the compiler

This could have been avoided easily if you compiled with `-Wall` that I highly recommend:

```
~$ gcc -Wall ifeq.c && ./a.out
ifeq.c:3:3: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
   if (x = 2) {
   ^
// other warnings
```